# JDialog.pack() hides JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jdialog, pack

I am trying to write a form in java, but after dynamically inserting JLabels to the current JDialog and doing a `pack()` the windows is resized to minimum. The JLabels are displayed, but I have to resize the window manually.
Here is the part where the JLabels are inserted:

```
public void displayQuizz(Test quiz){
        int xLable = 44;
        int yLable = 41;
        int widthLable = 403;
        int heightLable = 70;
        int noOfQuestion = 1;
        for(Question question : quiz.getQuestions()){
            JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel(Integer.toString(noOfQuestion) + ". " + question.getStatement());
            lblNewLabel.setBounds(xLable, yLable, widthLable, heightLable);
            contentPanel.add(lblNewLabel);
            contentPanel.revalidate();
            contentPanel.repaint();
            this.pack();

            noOfQuestion++;
            yLable += heightLable;
        }



    }
```

Comment: Don't use `setBounds()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pack()` method sets the size of a `Window` (where `JFrame` and `JDialog` are subclasses from) to the **preferred size**.

The preferred size is determined by

- The `LayoutManager`, which takes the arrangement of the components and
  their preferred size into account
- The component itself, if it does not have a layout manager

As you don't use a layout manager in your example (and set the bounds of the label manually), you also have to **specify the preferred size yourself** (see `getPreferredSize()`, the default is 0x0, that's the problem you encountered).

I'd encourage you to get used to **always use layout managers** (there's quite a lot of them, and you can easily write your own layout manager strategy if none suffices your needs).

Comment: Thank you. I was using Absolute Layout